# JQuery DataTable plugin not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have a bootstrap page with a table loaded from a MySQL db. The table shows but it doesn't show up with the desired format.

The table is set up here.

```
            <script type ="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#job_table').DataTable();
            } ); >
            </script>

                <table id="job_table"
                       class = "table dataTable"
                       data-pagination ="true">
                    <thread>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Job Title </th>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Date Posted</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thread>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            $result = mysqli_query($link,"Select * From Jobs");

                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                            ?>
                            <tr class="info">
                                <td></td>
                                <td><?=$row['job_id']?></td>
                                <td><?=$row['name']?></td>
                                <td><?=$row['comp_name']?></td>
                                <td><?=$row['pay']?></td>
                                <td><?=$row['location']?></td>
                                <td><?=$row['date_posted']?></td>                                                                </tr>
                        <?php
                                }
                                ?>

                    </tbody>
```

This is what i have in the header section

```
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="bootstrap/js/respond.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

The table displays data but the pagination setting in the table doesn't do anything when added. The Javascript I have to set up the table in the dataTable doesn't do anything either. I"m not sure what i'm missing.

This is the source of the html table. The rest was omitted because this table has about 500 rows of data.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="joblist">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Active Employment Listings</h3>
            </div>
            <script type ="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#job_table').DataTable();
            } ); >
            </script>

                <table id="job_table"
                       class = "table dataTable"
                       data-pagination ="true">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Job Title </th>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Date Posted</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead> 
                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr class="info">
                                <td></td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>VP Marketing</td>
                                <td>Devify</td>
                                <td>22.38</td>
                                <td>222 Lillian Hill</td>
                                <td>2015-02-17</td> 
                             </tr>
                                                        <tr class="info">
                                <td></td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>Administrative </td>
                                <td>Skiba</td>
                                <td>10.92</td>
                                <td>3 Corscot Terrace</td>
                                <td>2015-02-03</td> 
                             </tr>
```

Comment: pretty sure thread should be thead

Comment: you also never end the row in tbody

Comment: fix those let me know

Comment: @JoshuaByer Thanks for the reply.  You're right i changed thread to thead  and i included </tr> to end the row. Is there anything else you would suggest? That jquery plugin for the dataTable still doesn't appear.

Comment: view the source of the non working html table as html, and than paste it into your question.

Comment: @JoshuaByer I did. If you want to see anything else or if you want the link to the page let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: 6 cols i header and 7 in rows.

Comment: @JoshuaByer Thanks i'm not sure why the rows had an extra column. The table looks better but the pagination still doesn't work, neither does the dataTable i called with the javascript.